# Chain IK jittering when object moves or animates

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, inverse-kinematics

I am using Chain IK Constraint to simulate octopus like arms. But when I tried to move the arm or animate it, its jittering.

[image]

Handle's transform controlling by script

When I unparent the handle and disable the script same thing still happens.

Here is a video if situation: https://gfycat.com/measlyshamelessicefish

Answer (score 0):

I was using 25 bones while problem occurring then reduced bones to 17 and jittering is gone. This is nonsense there is no warning or info about unity docs or anywhere else "You can use maximum of X bones to work stable." Unity should have fix that.